# How can I determine if I am running in Android Wear or not?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a mobile and wear module in  Android Studio and they are both using a 'core' code-base...in that core-code, how could I determine whether my code is running on a 'wear' of 'mobile' module?  Should i use screen size?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Though this isn't officially documented (that I know of) you can determine whether the device is a watch or handheld by invoking either:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WATCH);
```

or by using:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
boolean isWatch = (config.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH;
```

I've tested both and they return true in my test Wear device (Moto 360) and false in a Nexus 5 phone.

(I found them by browsing the [API Differences Report for API level 4.4W (20)](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/20/changes.html). Though not guaranteed, these should be more future-proof than checking for the non-availabilty of other features, as those might be just temporary limitations).

Comment: Careful, let's not confuse WearOS with Android Watch devices.

Any manufacturer can create an Android device that has a small screen etc. and therefore must declare their device as having FEATURE_WATCH with UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH.

Only when Google's special system image is placed on such a device, with their own apps running as a companion device to another Android device, etc. is it called WearOS. This is very controlled by Google, as they choose which manufacturers to work with.

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html) says:

> Wearable apps can access much of the standard Android APIs, but don't
>   support the following APIs:

- android.webkit
- android.print
- android.app.backup
- android.appwidget
- android.hardware.usb

So you can use [`hasSystemFeature(String name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)) with those unsupported APIs (as input) to check whether the given feature name is one of the available features in your device. If it returned `false`, so you'd be in wear, otherwise you'd be in a mobile.