# How can my app figure out (at run-time) if it is running on Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I know how to get the build version that I'm running on:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      try {
        // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
        final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        ....
```

I would also like to have an (&& !wearable) in that if statement, since there is no actionBar on wearables.  It would be great if it was also included in the Build class somehow.

The app isn't officially wearable yet, but this is part of some shared code, so please don't tell me to pass it in from the wearable's activity.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if I am running wear or mobile code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406708/how-can-i-determine-if-i-am-running-wear-or-mobile-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to determine if you are on a watch, I'd try `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()`, to see if the device [has `FEATURE_WATCH`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_WATCH). Quoting the docs:

> Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): This is a device dedicated to showing UI on a watch. A watch here is defined to be a device worn on the body, perhaps on the wrist. The user is very close when interacting with the device.

However, as there are other scenarios where there is no action bar (e.g., TV apps), you might consider calling `getActionBar()` (for the native action bar) or `getSupportActionBar()` (for the `appcompat-v7` action bar) and see if it returns `null`.

Comment: I did this: if((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) && (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("FEATURE_WATCH"))) {
 and that stopped the crash.  Funny thing was it was actually the getActionBar() that crashes on Android Wear, even with a try {}catch{} around it.  getActionBar() does not like to be called at ALL on wear devices.

Comment: Careful, there is a difference between an Android Watch device, and WearOS (previously named Android Wear). Any manufacturer can create an Android device with a small screen and therefore must declare Watch feature & ui. But only by invitation from Google can the Google WearOS system image be put on such a device (which runs as a companion device only, has various google apps, etc.).